# How to add a colour to the placeholder of angucomplete-alt

Tags: angularjs

I have an angucomplete-alt input field , and my desired functionality is to change the colour of the placeholder to blue , when someone focusses on it..

`<div tpcomplete-alt='true' input-class='isused form-control' match-class='autocomplete-highlight' name='name' minlength='3' placeholder='Skill Name, E.g. Java' selected-object="onSelectSkill" title-field="text" remote-url='/api/skills?q=' override-suggestions="true" style='width:150px;'></div>`

Adding a class to 'input-class' only changes the colour of the text i type, but i want to change the colour of the placeholder. Can anyone tell me the right way to do it ..
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should specify id of your div then try to add class like this :

HTML:

```
<div id='ex1' tpcomplete-alt='true' input-class='isused form-control' match-class='autocomplete-highlight' name='name' minlength='3' placeholder='Skill Name, E.g. Java' selected-object="onSelectSkill" title-field="text" remote-url='/api/skills?q=' override-suggestions="true" style='width:150px;'></div>
```

CSS:

```
#ex1_value:placeholder-shown {
    color: #000;
}

#ex1_value::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;
}
#ex1_value:-moz-placeholder {
    color: #000;

}
#ex1_value::-moz-placeholder {
    color: #000;

}
#ex1_value:-ms-input-placeholder {
    color: #000;

}
```

Note : When you give id as ex1
It will create a child id for placeholder as ex1_value